# phpWhois via a proxy

Tags: php, proxy, whois

I am playing around with phpWhois: https://github.com/phpWhois/phpWhois

It's installed, and works great. But I would like to do the WHOIS request via a proxy IP. WHOIS servers often block IP's when they make too many requests, and therefor I want to use various proxies to ensure I don't get blocked.

phpWhois has proxy support as I can set: `$allowproxy = true;`

But apart from that, I see no documentation on how tell the script which proxies/ports to use. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: There is no concept of proxies in `whois` protocol. You can just use it from various endpoints, using standard methods like tunnels, socks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look into that [source code](https://github.com/phpWhois/phpWhois/blob/master/src/WhoisClient.php#L203):

```
fputs($ptr, trim($query_args) . "\r\n");
```

I'm sorry, this class doesn't support any proxy. You'll need a SOCKS implementation, and PHP doesn't support that with `fputs()` on a socket.

However I can recommend my [Whois API](http://whois-api.domaininformation.de/) which reliefs you from that complexity. [whois-api-php](https://github.com/whois-server-list/whois-api-php)
 would be a PHP client:

```
$whoisApi = new whoisServerList\WhoisApi("apiKey");
echo $whoisApi->query("whois.verisign-grs.com", "example.net");
```